# Failed to refresh Gradle project

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio 0.4.2 and I am facing the problem..
Here is the error.

> Failed to refresh Gradle project 'epilepticapp'
>          You are using Gradle version 1.10, which is not supported. Please use version 1.9.
>          Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the 
>   project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)

Comment: You are better off switch back to using intellij, the effort it takes to get gradles working isn't really worth it at the minute. I'm hoping this is fixed when AS is out of the beta

Comment: I would strongly recommend upgrading to the latest version of Android Studio. 0.4.2 is very old and a mountain of bugs have been fixed since then.